# how to set camera adjustments (focus, apperture, white balance)

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, camera, camera-calibration

I am beginner. I am working with pinhole cameras. 
I  have set a basic questions: 
1) Focus
I know that I can set the focus manually. 
Can I do that with software/programming side ? 
How can I check that focus is okay ? only visual check ? 
Could you advice any algorithm ?

2)
If I have a camera always on the same position. Is it worth to perform autofocus ?

3) White balance
How to calculate optimal values of RGB ? 
How can I check white balance in the image ?

5) About camera apperture

I would be appreciate for any help please.

Comment: One question per question (post), please. You seem to have enough here for at least 4 decent posts...

Comment: And always google first. Most of these questions have answers available online. At least, if you decide to open them, show some effort on trying to solve them by yourself first; then people will be more inclined to help you.